What is a convex-concave lens?
I came across this term while studying for optics, and I'm unsure as to what this means. My thinking is that it might be a meniscus lens, but the text separately give two different models for each lens. Edit: is there a difference between a convex-concave lens and a meniscus lens?
Here's the model for the convex-concave lens:

And here's the model for the meniscus lens:

I guess it might have something to do with the curvatures, but I'm not sure.

You may want to compare to a regular convex lens, where the lens is curved outwards on both sides.
Concave is like the side of a bowl you fill with soup and it stays in the bowl.  If you flipped the bowl upside down, you would be looking at the convex side, which wouldn't hold soup, of course.
Clearly, the model you show has both a convex and concave side, like a bowl.

Is there a difference between a convex-concave lens and a meniscus lens?

I believe the terms are interchangeable.  This wiki page has more details:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens.  A quote: "Convex-concave (meniscus) lenses can be either positive or negative, depending on the relative curvatures of the two surfaces."
